# Adding a root xml element before another root C#

Tags: c#, xml, xmlroot

I have an xml document that follows:

```
-<Machines>


-<Machine>


-<InstallPath >

<Component "/>

<Component "/>

<Component "/>

<Component "/>

<Component "/>


</InstallPath>

</Machine>
</Machines>
```

I need to add a root Manifest element before Machines pragmatically using C#.

I tried the following code and I get an error saying that the document is not properly constructed.

Here is the code I am trying:

```
using (XmlReader reader = cmd.ExecuteXmlReader())
                    {
                        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(reader);
                        doc.Root.AddBeforeSelf(new XElement("Manifest"));
                        string path = outputPath + "\\" + xmlFileName;

                        doc.Save(path);    
                    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XML can only have one "root" element.  So the structure you're wanting is not valid:

```
<Manifest>
    ...
</Manifest>
<Machines>
    ...
</Machines>
```

If you want two sibling elements, they would need to be contained in another parent element.

> I want the Manifest element to surround the Machines element and the Machines element to contain the rest of the xml

Then you need to create a *new* document:

```
XDocument newDoc = new XDocument(new XElement("Manifest", doc.Root));
```

This creates a new `XDocument` with a `Manifest` root tag, whose content is the root (and contents) of the original document.

Comment: Sorry Im complete new to xml, I dont want two "root elements" I want the Manifest element to surround the Machines element and the Machines element to contain the rest of the xml if that makes sense

Comment: So if it is possible to insert the Manifest element around the Machines element and have the Manifest element as the root instead of the Machines that would be Ideal.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new element with the current `Root` and put it in a new `XDocument`:

```
XDocument newDoc = new XDocument(new XElement("Manifest", doc.Root));
```